# Maximum wait time in queue in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to set maximum wait time on Executor Services ?!

For example when you pass two while true runnable to `SingleThreadExecutor` the first one will work forever , and the second one just wait for ever.

I expect to got an TimeOutException about second Runnable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("#"+ finalI + " Runnable !");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: it appears your runnable task will never finish? So this thread will run, print, sleep, run, print, sleep ad infinitum so why would another thread ever be executed by this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to set maximum wait time on Executor Services ?!

If you are talking about waiting for a job to start to run, the answer unfortunately is "not easily".  There are some ways you can do it using the queue in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` but they would be considered hacks and aren't recommended.  You could also extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` but that could get complicated.

One [better] solution would be to manage your queue externally.

```
// synchronous queue waits for someone to take() from the queue before returning
final BlockingQueue<Runnable> jobQueue = new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>();
...
// submit all of your threads who get jobs from your queue to run
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         while (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
              try {
                  Runnable job = jobQueue.take();
                  job.run();
              } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                  // always recommended
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                  return;
              }
         }
    }
});
...
// now we can try to add a job into the queue but if it is full, offer may timeout
if (!queue.offer(new Runnable() { ... }, 2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    // timed out
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How should the executor be configured ? should the internal queue be of null size (a SynchronousQueue)  ?  What if the job should return a result and best use the parallelism  of more than one Thread of the executor ?

Answer (score 1):

Your executor has only a single thread. It will queue different Runnable tasks internally and try to finish them one by one. If the first task never finishes (because it's a while true loop), the second task will never start.

You can use `submit` instead of `execute` to get a Future object, and perform a `get` operation with a timeout instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    List<Future> future = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        future.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("#"+ finalI + " Runnable !");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    // Check if second task finishes in the next 2 seconds, and throw a TimeoutException if it does not

    try {
        future.get(1).get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Once you have determined your task is timing out, you can cancel it by using `future.get(1).cancel(false)`

However, if rejecting a task when every thread is busy works for you, you could try this approach:

```
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                queue);
```

This ExecutorService will automatically reject tasks if all threads are busy.

Comment: i know that too ;) , but what about getting a TimeOutException ?!

Comment: There won't be a timeout. However, you can use `submit` instead of `execute` to receive a Future. Then you can do a `future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLSECONDS)` and it will throw a TimeoutException if the execution of the task has not finished on time. I can extend my answer to show some code implementing this behaviour :)

Comment: i will appreciate you if show me a useful sample code

Comment: Does it work for you? Feel free to let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Actually not , I am trying to develop a thread pool that reject new jobs if it is too busy after specific time out. also `future.get` will block Thread and is not useful in this case . is there any method to being aware about how busy the thread pool is ?! , for example how many threads are working , remaining threads count and ETC. maybe this can help use to prevent submitting new runnables !

Comment: Yeah the `future.get()` waits for completion of the job.  It doesn't stop the job from being submitted.

Comment: I am not aware of any non-custom solutions with timeout, but there is an easy way of rejecting a task immediately if all threads are busy. I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: Good Job ! , Thank you ;)

Comment: ExecutorService is actually doing same thing as @Gray's answer , also with his answer we can customize timeOut and task handling.

Comment: You still have to block the main thread waiting for an answer to see if the thread pool is busy or not when you use the `offer` (similar to my future.get() check). The only difference is, in my case you actually submit the job and you check for its status, and in @Gray's answer you check if you can submit the job or not. I am guessing everything will depend on you application architecture, if you want to block immediately after sending a task, @Gray's answer should be better. If you want to perform some other logic and check later if the task was finished, my approach should perform better.